# React testing error Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, async-await, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a functional component which I am trying to test and there seems to be some issue around the endpoint call via axios.

```
const url = user.myUrl + "/someEndpoint";
const RESPONSE = await axios.post(url);
console.log("RESPONSE ::::::::::::::::::::::::" + RESPONSE);
```

The test is as below;

```
test("Validate something", async () => {
    const {container} = render(
            <MyComponent url={url} />
    );
    expect(await container.getElementsByClassName('someGrid').length).toBe(2);
});
```

When I run the test, I get the below error;

```
Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?
    Attempted to log "RESPONSE ::::::::::::::::::::::::[object Object]".
```

PS: I am mocking endpoints via msw.

Comment: Its been a while since you asked your question, but did my answer help you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `MyComponent` has an effect in it i.e. an axios POST, you need to wait for the result. Hence try changing your test to:

```
test("Validate something", async () => {
    const {container} = render(<MyComponent url={url} />);
    await waitFor(() => expect(container.getElementsByClassName('someGrid').length).toBe(2));
});
```

(You'll most likely need to import `waitFor` if you don't already use it)